# How do I subclass AVAudioUnit?

Tags: core-audio, audiounit, avaudioengine

Since the way to instantiate an `AVAudioUnit` is this:

```
[AVAudioUnit instantiateWithComponentDescription:componentDescription options:0 completionHandler:^(__kindof AVAudioUnit * _Nullable audioUnit, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    }];
```

How am I supposed to subclass `AVAudioUnit`? I have tried this:

```
[MySubclassOfAVAudioUnit instantiateWithComponentDescription:componentDescription options:0 completionHandler:^(__kindof AVAudioUnit * _Nullable audioUnit, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    }];
```

But the `audioUnit` that is returned in the block is still of type `AVAudioUnit` and NOT `MySubclassOfAVAudioUnit`.

---

Per Rhythmic Fistman's response, I am registering my custom `AUAudioUnit` subclass with Apple's example code:

```
componentDescription.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Effect;
componentDescription.componentSubType = 0x666c7472; /*'fltr'*/
componentDescription.componentManufacturer = 0x44656d6f; /*'Demo'*/
componentDescription.componentFlags = 0;
componentDescription.componentFlagsMask = 0;
```

I want my `AVAudioUnit` subclass to always use my `AUAudioUnit`.

Comment: I realised my answer was wrong, you can only subclass `AUAudioUnit` & have it wrapped in the correct type of `AVAudioUnit` subclass. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `instantiateWithComponentDescription:completionHandler:`

> The returned AVAudioUnit instance normally will be of a subclass (AVAudioUnitEffect,
>           AVAudioUnitGenerator, AVAudioUnitMIDIInstrument, or AVAudioUnitTimeEffect), selected
>           according to the component's type.

**UPDATE**
I got this wrong - you *can't* instantiate your own `AVAudioUnit` subclass, you can only instantiate your `AUAudioUnit`, wrapped in the relevant built-in AVFoundation `AVAudioUnit` subclass (e.g. `AVAudioUnitEffect`, etc).

The following code causes `MyAUAudioUnit`, a subclass of `AUAudioUnit` to be instantiated:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface MyAUAudioUnit : AUAudioUnit {

}
@end

@implementation MyAUAudioUnit
    // implement it here
@end

// later
- (void)instantiateMyAUAudioUnitWrappedInAVAudioUnit {
    // register it (need only be done once)
    AudioComponentDescription desc;
    desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Effect;
    desc.componentSubType = 0x666c7472; /*'fltr'*/
    desc.componentManufacturer = 0x44656d6f; /*'Demo'*/
    desc.componentFlags = 0;
    desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;

    [AUAudioUnit registerSubclass:MyAUAudioUnit.class asComponentDescription:desc name:@"MyAU" version:1];

    // Instantiate as many times as you like:
    [AVAudioUnit instantiateWithComponentDescription:desc options:0 completionHandler:^(AVAudioUnit * audioUnit, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"AVAudioUnit: %@, error: %@", audioUnit, error);
    }];
}
```

**WRONG BIT**

So to have your  `AVAudioUnit` subclass instantiated, you must first register it with the *`AUAudioUnit`* method:

`+[AUAudioUnit registerSubclass:asComponentDescription:name:version:]`

There is a code snippet and some possible gotchas in [this devforum thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/39715).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I followed exactly that procedure, but instantiateWithComponentDescription will never return an instance of my subclass. The discussion thread doesn't seem to address this issue, unfortunately. I'll add a little more detail to the question.

Comment: can you show how you're calling `registerSubclass`? maybe show some of your `AUAudioUnit` subclass too?

Comment: Just curious to know if the OP figured this out. I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: There's code linked in @hotpaw2's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46775145/22147