# How do I create an AUAudioUnit that implements multiple audio units?

Tags: ios, macos, audio, core-audio, avaudioengine

In Apple's docs for creating an AUAudio Unit (Here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/auaudiounit/1387570-initwithcomponentdescription)
they claim that

> A single audio unit subclass may implement multiple audio units—for example, an effect that can also function as a generator, or a cluster of related effects.

There are no examples of this online that I can find.  Ideally it would be nice if your answer/solution involved using Swift and AVAudioEngine but I'd happily accept any answer that gets me moving in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the 2017 WWDC session on Core Audio, Apple says not to use Swift inside the real-time audio context (the working guts of an AUAudioUnit subclass).

Comment: Hello Aurelius, have you made any progress on this topic?

Answer (score 3):

I posted some source code to my test app which instantiates an AVAudioUnit generator subclass object using AVAudioEngine, Swift and C, on GitHub here:

https://github.com/hotpaw2/auv3test5

Note that [Apple recommends NOT using Swift](http://Apple%20recommends%20NOT%20using%20Swift) inside the real-time audio context, so that portion of my source code is written in C, inside an Objective C wrapper class.

If you use [initWithComponentDescription:options:error:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/auaudiounit/1387664-initwithcomponentdescription?language=objc), you can pass an option to configure your new audio unit subclass object to do whatever (using something like a switch statement on the option).

Comment: Let me check out your code and see if it is what I need. Thanks for responding!

Comment: So yeah this is helpful, but it doesn't implement multiple audio units in one unless i am missing something?

Comment: See the last paragraph about adding an option.

Comment: yeah, sorry but I feel like the hard part of this question remains unanswered. The last paragraph is where I'm unsure of the best way to do things.

Comment: @hotpaw2 Do you by chance know how I can make your code to play specific musical notes, like an a C or an F#? Wouldn't I need to figure out the specific hertz for each note?

Comment: Musical note pitch frequency? That’s a separate question, possibly a duplicate of other questions already answered here on stackoverflow (or Wikipedia)